# Is there a way to search for controls in VB.Net Designer?

Tags: vb.net

I have a Form that has about 130 controls (36 Text boxes, 36 Labels, 5 Timers, 34 Buttons and 19 Picture Boxes) in the Vb.Net Designer window.

To select one of the controls e.g "**Button34**" out of the 130 controls that I have on the form so that I can rename it to "**btnUpload**" I have to click through all 34 buttons to know find which button is it on the form .

I observed that the **search** tool in VB.Net is designed to search through codes and not through controls you have on a form.

So my question is that is there a way to search a form for controls in VB.Net?

This will make navigating and selecting controls much easier instead of having to click through so many controls to find which I need.

Thanks.

Comment: Select the control from the dropdown in the property editor.  The IDE will change the references for you when you change the `Name` property (not Text)

Comment: You can try to locate it in the document outline window or in the dropdown  on the top of the properties window, but I think the easiest way is to simply open the Designer.vb code, search and rename from there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can select control in `Properties Window`

`View > Properties Window` or `F4` like below :

[image]

Or You can select control in `Document Outline`

`View > Other Windows > Document Outline` or `Ctl + ALT + T` like below :

[image]

Comment: I have never used the **Properties Window** or **Document Outline** These are really both wonderful windows to solve search/select control. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Glad to hear that! Thank you too :)

Comment: I Edited the question I asked so that it can help others have a better idea of the problem I was trying to solve. Thanks once again.